# How to break line of body of Email attachment

Tags: apex, email

I have to send the attachment with the email through apex class and the body need to be in a format that needs a line break as html is not supported in attachment.

Can someone help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think in the header you need to mention the content-type. If you mention the 'content type' as 'text/html' use <br> or if if you mention it as 'text/plain' then use  /n for the newline.

Comment: Which file type you are attaching or what are you building to attach ? @Mahi

Comment: I am sending the invitation detail in the attachment and so i need to send information in different lines. If a user click on this attachment it should open in outlook and when I use content-type then it open with any default browser and do not work and also <br> and /n does not work.

Comment: It's not /n. It's \n.

Comment: yes, i tried \n but it is not working...

Comment: Assuming this isn't yet working, can you post code?